# Max Height as Percentage

Tags: .net, wpf

Have a ScrollViewer in a Grid.Row where I want the ScrollViewer height to be auto and a max of 1/3 of the container
It only wants to take a number pixels for MaxHeight

Comment: A third of the row, or a third of the whole grid?

Comment: Is this you talking about - `<RowDefinition Width=".3*"/>`?

Comment: @RohitVats I'm guessing you meant `<RowDefinition Height=".3*"/>`

Comment: @RohitVats: that won't work if other content is sized using methods other than the `*`. For example, if there's a row with an explicit 400-pixel height, the `.3*` will be 0.3 of the *remaining* height after the 400 is allocated.

Answer (score -2):

```
         <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight=".33*" />
                <RowDefinition Height=".66*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.row="0">
            <!-- scroll viewer -->
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.row="1">
            <!-- other -->
            </grid>
         </Grid>
```

I think this may be along the lines of what you want ?

Comment: Agreed - error is "string cannot be converted to length".  Downvoted.

Comment: It might just be missing 0's ... try 0.33 and 0.66